# Flask error - sqlite3.OperationalError: near "subject": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I've been working through the Flask tutorial and am getting stuck.

In order to run the application, you have to import and run the `init_db()` function through the Python shell to create the database.

The application worked fine, but now when I run it (I'm sure I didn't change anything!), I get the following error:

```
>>> from flaskr import init_db
>>> init_db()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "flaskr.py", line 39, in init_db
db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "subject": syntax error
```

I've copied and pasted the original documentation code several times, but it still spits out the same errors.

```
36 def init_db():
37 with closing(connect_db()) as db:
38     with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
39         db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
40     db.commit()
```

Comment: You are asking SQLite to perform the SQL statements found in the `schema.sql` file. The error says that SQLite is complaining about a syntax error, so the error is in the `schema.sql` file. Make sure it looks like [what is provided in the tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/schema/#tutorial-schema). Add the content of that file to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to indent it:

```
36 def init_db():
37     with closing(connect_db()) as db:
38         with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
39             db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
40         db.commit()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The error message shows that the problem is with running the SQL file. If you believe the person has indented their Python incorrectly, that should be a comment (unless the question is asking why they are getting an error message relating to Python indentation, which this is not).

Comment: Hm.. Oh yeah you're correct. But i think i'll need more info from the OP, since I have no idea what his query looks like.

Comment: That's true, right now there doesn't appear to be any way to answer this question without the OP posting what their SQL file looks like.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same question, but I find that sqlite3 has restrict format requirement for script file. For the example in tutorial, the most common mistake may be that for the last item in your table declaration, no more comma is allowed in the end(I think some guys may want to add one for easy extension in the future ). Hope this help~